# url rewriting by .htaccess files in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am rewriting my problem .
Below I am giving all the details of what i am trying to do, and what is the result I am getting. I hope to be very clear this time. I have a samples page here www.broadcast2world.com/samples.php. 
All the links and data which we see on the page is coming from a database. Now suppose we click on a link "More Info" for a particular video say social control. A specific href for that video is triggered as `<a href="video.php?pid='.$id.'">` . It passes its id over url in the format `http://www.broadcast2world.com/video.php?pid=66.`

I catch that id into a variable using

```
if(!isset($_GET['pid'])){
    $pageid='66';
}
else{
  $pageid=$_GET['pid'];  
}
```

Using the $pageid variable, I run a query which ultimately prepare the page for that particular video.

What my SEO guy need is a url in the format www.broadcast2world.com/video/name-of-the-video.

Now the problem is that if I make a mod_rewrite amendments which is wonderfully explained by Ben below, I am not able to figure out, how to link that name-of-the-video to its id. I am sure there must be something I have to modify while creating specific url for videos as explained above. But I really don't know what? Thanks again for your wonderful support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of id, you have to search the database based on title then.

Here are what you are going to need.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^videos/(.*)$ video.php?title=$1
```

**Link generation**

```
$title = "...";
$title = str_replace(" ", "-", $title); //add dashes on the link
echo "<a href="videos/$title">Click Me</a>";
```

Comment: Hi Starx, it worked perfectly and I am getting the data from database. But the styling of my page has completely gone haywire. When I have view source of the page I noticed that instead of getting css or js from /js/script.js or /css/style.css it is trying to fetch them from videos/js/script.js.How can I ensure that for fetching the support scripts it does not add that extra "videos" in the url. You can view the page at http://www.broadcast2world.com/videos/avitas-video. Just noticed that even for all the links like aboutus, it is adding an extra /videos/

Comment: @CodeRoad, See the update, it specifies the condition to apply the redirection, only if the resource is not a file or a directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a column in your `videos` table in which you will store `name-of-the-video` that is suitable to be put in URL. You will need to `UPDATE` all your videos and set the `name-of-the-video` to a unique value for each video. From then on it will be simple to fetch a video by name instead of by id.